# Vbs CopyFile to User Selected Folder is not working properly

Tags: vbscript

My Vbscript is for prompt to select a folder and then copy a file to the seleted folder
My Code is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strPath, pth, fso

strPath = SelectFolder( "" )
pth = """" & strPath & "\" & """"

If strPath = vbNull Then
  WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
Else
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt", strPath

' fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt", pth

msgbox("Copy DONE")
End If


Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )

Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell

On Error Resume Next
SelectFolder = vbNull

Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder Please", 0, myStartFolder )

If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objshell  = Nothing
On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

When i am using **fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt", strPath**  it only copies to the path if the path is like **c:\ or d:\**  but does not copying file to like '**d:\folder\test\**' if selected, it showing error - " **PERMISSON DENIED** ", but the path has not set any attribute

When i am using **fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt", pth**  , it showing error - " **Bad File Name or Number** " for any folder selection

what should i do? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I changed line 5 to the following:

```
pth = strPath & "\"
```

and then used the 'fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt", pth' line to do the copy. That worked.

Comment: Ok Thanks @bluebearr ,but
will it work on chosing C
drive . for this after adding
the \ sign pth will be look
like  C:\\ , will it work? –

Comment: It worked on my tests on Windows 7. But remember that by default you can't copy to the root of C: without running as an Administrator. If the doubled up backslash concerns you, you can use  
    pth = strPath & "\"  
    if Right(pth, 1) <> "\" Then pth = pth & "\"

Comment: If you always want a path to end with a single backslash, you can also use the `BuildPath()` function. For example, `fso.BuildPath(strPath, "\")`.

Comment: Thank you guys. but I go with Bluebearr and its workd.

Answer (score 0):

i discovered that if user select d:\ drive then its lenth is 3
so my edited code is

```
dim ptlen,finalpatg
ptlen=len(strPath)
if ptlen = 3 then //for only drive selection the ptlen will be 3 so no need to add \
finalpath=strPath
else
 finalpath=strPath & "\" //add slash to path if ptlen not =3
end if

fso.CopyFile "H:\new\file.txt",finalpath
```

its workd successfully